# JTable Column header

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I'm trying to display more detailed column headers, without using the database column names supplied by [`DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel()`](http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/59-resultset-to-tablemodel). Here is my code:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
String sql = "SELECT * From product";
String col[] = {"Product No", "Name", "Price", "QOH"};
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
try {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(col);
    ProductList_tbl.setModel(dtm);
    ProductList_tbl.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
```

but it still displays the database table column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing which `DbUtils` you're using, a few things come to mind:

- Use an SQL alias for each desired column, instead of the wildcard, e.g.

  ```
  SELECT column_name AS alias_name;
  ```
- Update the `TableModel` *after* it has been created by `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel()` using whatever API is available.

Comment: @trashgod : I just wonder wonder how great **SO** and their members are :). But a li'l question as I had a similar scenario, if I update the table model after doing `(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));` it gives me an empty resultset. Would you please comment on that?

Comment: Invoking `rs.beforeFirst()` should move the cursor its initial position, before the first row.

Answer (score 2):

If the DbUtils doesn't provide an API to change the column value then you should be able to use the standard table classes:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(...);
tc.setHeaderValue( "..." );
```